# post an image to an express server from the front end - Ionic2

Tags: image, cordova, ionic2, file-transfer

i am trying to post an image to a a backend server that is an Express Server.

I am using cordova file transfer(installed through **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer** )

I have imported the file transfer like this:

```
import {Transfer} from 'ionic-native';
```

here is my component that posts the file to the server

```
save() {

    base64Image = open("/Users/user1/1.jpg");
    let ft = new Transfer();
    let filename = "example" + ".jpg";
    let options = {
      fileKey: 'file',
            fileName: filename,
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            chunkedMode: false,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
            },
            params: {
                fileName: filename
            }
    };

    ft.upload(base64Image, "http://localhost:3500/api/v1/file", options, false);

  }
```

the error i get whenever i call the save function is:

```
FileTransfer is not defined
```

help will be appreciated

Comment: try to install with ionic since you are using ionic-native `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save`. The save option is to ensure there is an entry in `config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Install with ionic since you are using `ionic-native`.

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save`.

The save option is to ensure there is an entry in **config.xml**.
Also call any plugin within

```
platform.ready().then(()=>{})
```

Plugins are loaded after the app is loaded.

**UPDATE:**
Cordova is not supported and most plugins will not load with `ionic serve` command.
You need to run it in an emulator or a device.

Comment: that actually didn't solve my problem..... and also `open("/Users/user1/1.jpg");` is this the way how to assign an image to a variable

Comment: no..You should use  for http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/camera/ for images.. is it from gallery?

Comment: but that wont causr Filetransfer not defined

Comment: how are you running this?

Comment: through the browser..... ionic serve -l ......not using any platforms..... I mean emulators

Comment: Cordova is not supprorted in ionic serv